# Where to hold PL/SQL constants?

Tags: plsql

Where do you normally store your PL/SQL constants? On the package-body level? In the specification? I've also seen some people holding constants in a specialized package just for constants. What are best practices in this area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One downside to having constants in a package body or spec is that when you recompile the package, any user sessions that had the package state in the PGA would get ORA-04068. For this reason, in one large development environment we adopted the convention of having a separate spec-only package to hold the constants (and package globals if any) for each package. We'd then impose a rule saying that these spec-only packages were only allowed to be referenced by their "owning" package - which we enforced at code review. Not a perfect solution, but it worked for us at the time.

For the same reason, I'd never recommend one-constant-package-to-rule-them-all because every time someone needs to introduce a new constant, or modify an existing one, all user sessions get ORA-04068.

Comment: Epilogue for completeness: best practice normally is to define everything as close to their use as possible: if the constant is only used by one procedure, define it in that procedure; if the constant is only used in a package body, define it in the package body (except for the ORA-04068 problem noted above - which becomes less of an issue in 11gR2, it should be mentioned, if editions are used).

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, you want to keep them in the specification so other packages can use them, especially as parameters when calling functions and procedures from your package.

Only when you want to keep them private to the package, you should put them int the body.

Having a package just for constants might be a good idea for those constants that are not related to any piece of code in particular, but relevant for the whole schema.

Answer (score 3):

For our application, all constants are in a table. A simple function is used to extract them. No problem with recompilation, ORA-04068, ...

Comment: So then they are not really "constants", are they? :-)

Comment: _"One man's constant is another man's variable."_ - Alan Perlis

Answer (score 2):

Best option in my opinion. Store the "constant" in a table and create a generic function to get the values. No 04068

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the constants to be, by default, in the package body unless you use the constant as a parameter value for one of your public package procedures/functions or as a return value for your functions.

The problem with putting your constants in the package specification is that if you need to change the constant's type, other packages might fail that use the constant because it was just there. If the constant was private in the first place, then you don't need to perform an impact analysis for each change.

If you need to store contants like default language or stuff like that, then I would encapsulate those contants in functions like `get_default_language` etc. and keep the constants private.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a concern about having "one package to rule the constants" because package state -- constants, variables, and code -- get cached in the user's PGA at first invocation of any public variable or package.  A package constant, if public, should be scoped to the package, and used by only by the methods of the package.

A constant whose scope spans packages should be in a code table with a description, joined in as required.  Constant's aren't and variables don't, after all.  Having a key-value-pair table of "constants" makes them all public, and makes changing them dynamically possible.

Answer (score 0):

What if we use parameterless function named the same way as constant instead of using  constant in the package. In that case we can add new function/constant to the package, change returning value of function or even remove some function from the package freely and we'll not get ORA 04068 after recompile it.
Inside implementation part of the function in the package body we can use constant as a returning value, though it's unnecessarily because we obviously can't change returning value. Also we can use in function signature some special performance technics, such as deterministic or maybe even result cash.
As a positive side effect we get ability to use constant in sql queries.